# Summing 2 rows of a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Searched around and can't find an exact solution to this problem..

I want to sum 2 rows of a column and form a column

Example..

```
ROW A  
Z   1 
Y   2 
X   3 
    4 
    5
    6 
    7 
    8

Desired
    ROW A B 
    Z   1 3
    Y   2 5
    X   3 7
        4 9
        5 11
        6 13
        7 15
        8
```

Basically I want to take sum of row Y and Z of column A and put it into row Z of column B.

I am playing around the idea of grouping by index + 1 but can't get around it

Comment: Can you show the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift):

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(10)})

df['B'] = df.A + df.shift(-1).A
```

output:

```
   A     B
0  0   1.0
1  1   3.0
2  2   5.0
3  3   7.0
4  4   9.0
5  5  11.0
6  6  13.0
7  7  15.0
8  8  17.0
9  9   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rolling` with a window of `2`

```
df.assign(B=df.A.rolling(2).sum().shift(-1))

   A     B
0  0   1.0
1  1   3.0
2  2   5.0
3  3   7.0
4  4   9.0
5  5  11.0
6  6  13.0
7  7  15.0
8  8  17.0
9  9   NaN
```